# Adjusting distance between points in RGraph (javascript)

Tags: javascript, plot, rgraph

I'm using RGraph's Line charts to plot some chronological data. It works fine, except that the distance between the successive points is always the same - irrespective of whether they are two hours or two months apart. I would like to customize it so that the distance represents the actual time interval between the points. Is this possible using the Line charts or any other charts in RGraph?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted RGraph support with the above question, and they have suggested that I use [Scatter charts](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/scatter.html) instead:

> You'd be better placed with Scatter chart. With this chart you can set
>   the maximum X value and the X axis is scaled (which you can show if
>   you wish).